# Why am I getting AbstractSafeParcelable not found error in Cordova Firebase plugin

Tags: android, cordova, firebase, ionic-framework

Hello I'm in trouble with the installation of a cordova plugin : cordova-plugin-firebase

Here the output of build :

```
BUILD FAILED

Total time: 1.223 secs
Error: /home/thor/Projects/App_CDP/platforms/android/gradlew: Command failed with exit code 1 Error output:
/home/thor/Projects/App_CDP/platforms/android/src/plugin/google/maps/GoogleMaps.java:479: error: cannot access AbstractSafeParcelable
    options.compassEnabled(controls.getBoolean("compass"));
           ^
  class file for com.google.android.gms.common.internal.safeparcel.AbstractSafeParcelable not found
 /home/thor/Projects/App_CDP/platforms/android/src/plugin/google/maps/GoogleMaps.java:717: error: cannot find symbol
    String msg = GooglePlayServicesUtil.getOpenSourceSoftwareLicenseInfo(activity);
                                   ^
  symbol:   method getOpenSourceSoftwareLicenseInfo(Activity)
  location: class GooglePlayServicesUtil
/home/thor/Projects/App_CDP/platforms/android/src/plugin/google/maps/AsyncLicenseInfo.java:22: error: cannot find symbol
    String licenseInfo = GooglePlayServicesUtil.getOpenSourceSoftwareLicenseInfo(mActivity);
                                           ^
  symbol:   method getOpenSourceSoftwareLicenseInfo(Activity)
  location: class GooglePlayServicesUtil
Note: Some input files use or override a deprecated API.
Note: Recompile with -Xlint:deprecation for details.
Note: Some input files use unchecked or unsafe operations.
Note: Recompile with -Xlint:unchecked for details.
3 errors

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* What went wrong:
Execution failed for task ':compileDebugJavaWithJavac'.
> Compilation failed; see the compiler error output for details.

* Try:
Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output.
```

I found that it was because `com.google.android.gms:play-services-maps` and `com.google.firebase:firebase-messaging` were not under the same version but i can't edit my `build.gradle` because it is generated every time i build

```
$ cat platforms/android/build.gradle

[...]

dependencies {
     compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: '*.jar')
    // SUB-PROJECT DEPENDENCIES START
    debugCompile(project(path: "CordovaLib", configuration: "debug"))
    releaseCompile(project(path: "CordovaLib", configuration: "release"))
    compile "com.google.gms:google-services:+"
    compile "com.google.firebase:firebase-core:+"
    compile "com.google.firebase:firebase-messaging:+"
    compile "com.google.firebase:firebase-crash:+"
    compile "com.google.firebase:firebase-config:+"
    compile "com.google.android.gms:play-services-maps:9.8.0"
    compile "com.google.android.gms:play-services-location:9.8.0"
    compile "com.facebook.android:facebook-android-sdk:4.+"
    // SUB-PROJECT DEPENDENCIES END
}

[...]
```

Any idea ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try using [cordova-android-play-services-gradle-release](https://github.com/dpa99c/cordova-android-play-services-gradle-release) to override the version of Play Services to align with Firebase:

```
cordova plugin add cordova-android-play-services-gradle-release --variable PLAY_SERVICES_VERSION=+
```

Comment: When i compile it say it is deprecated and will be removed in gradle 5 is it a good choice to use it anyway ?

Comment: The Cordova build stack uses deprecated APIs all over the place - I wouldn't worry about it

Comment: Alright, thanks :D. By the way do you have an idea for the 2 other errors : cannot find symbol ?
I found this topic related https://github.com/mapsplugin/cordova-plugin-googlemaps/issues/1646 but i'm not really familiar with cordova and i don't understand really well the problem :/

Comment: Alright i was searching and error in the wrong plugin, i actually had to update cordova-plugin-googlemaps